How do I distinguish between "e" the natural log base and a variable conventionally referred to as "e"?
How does one distinguish between the natural base, usually indicated with "e" and a coefficient that, due to historical reasons, is referred to as "e" (such as in Weibull functions for dose-response)?

You can't. If for some reason they have to appear in the same equation, you must rename one of them.

+1 for a question that unfortunately needs answering sometimes. To take a physicist's example, $\mathrm{e}^{eV/(k_BT)}$, with $e$ the charge of a proton.

The sum of a bunch of phase shifted currents might be $i = \sum_i, i_ie^{i\phi_i}$, which seems clear enough.

@Aruralreader Which is part of the reason people often replace $i$ as in $i^2=-1$ with $\mathrm{i}$ or $j$. If they're quirky, they might even use $\iota$.

Context! There exist different words that are spelled exactly the same. How to tell them apart?

One approach is to use bold/italic style variants: e, e, e, and e.  But it's probably less confusing to rename one of the e's.

@Aruralreader: Electrical engineers tend to use $j$ for the imaginary unit to avoid conflicting with $i$ for current.

In printed mathematics, the natural base should be set in roman type: $\mathrm e$, while symbols representing quantities that can vary (depending on context or units) should use the usual italic font: $e$.
(Added in response to comment) In general, roman type should be used for all symbols in mathematics that have a fixed meaning: $\mathrm{i,j,k}$ for the base elements of the complex numbers and quaternions; $\exp,\ln,\cos,$ and so on for standard functions; $\lim, \sup,\operatorname{argmin}, ...$ for standard operations; the differential symbol $\mathrm d$; the base symbols $\mathrm{J}$ for the Bessel function; $\mathrm C^n(X)$ for the real functions on $X$ with continuous $n$th derivative; $\mathrm{L,H,W}$ as the base symbols for the function spaces of Lebesgue, Hardy, Sobolev, etc. Notice also that the number realms $\Bbb{N,Z,Q,R,C,H}$ are always set in upright, not italic, type.

Thank you so much. I always feel like I am the only one who prefers $\int_a^b\mathrm e^{it},\mathrm dt$ over $\int_a^be^{it}dt$.

But I would not recommend this as a way to distinguish the two meanings within a single formula. That is asking too much of the reader's eyesight!

Or write $\mathrm{e}^x$ as $\exp x$.

I only downvoted because I agree with @TonyK—we shouldn't trust this mere font difference to distinguish between the two mathematical objects, so this isn't the best answer to the OP's specific question. (Personally I prefer the usual italic e to the roman e in math formulas, but that alone isn't a reason to downvote :) )

From the moment somebody writes this down, the difference disappears, hence my downvote.

Personally I don't like it for all the reasons given, but in the UK there is or was some official standard which prescribed this usage. So I think it's wrong to downvote the answer.

Would you use an upright lowercase roman for the constant relating the diameter of a circle with its perimeter, or is "$\pi$" ok?

@Didier : The default greek font in TeX is italic for lowercase and roman for uppercase. It is possible to get italic greek uppercase in TeX (which should be used, where appropriate, for variables)—but, AFAIK, not roman greek lowercase. The workaround is to type &#960 followed by a semicolon, not between dollar signs. I can't actually type the aforementioned semicolon here in the comment composition box, because the consequent six-character string just yields a blank.  However, in the box for questions or answers, it yields a perfect roman lowercase pi.

@Didier : For a roman pi, the typed string π is shorter than π and gives the same result.

@JohnBentin My question was not "How do you do this?" but a genuine "Would you?"

@Didier : I probably would (because I'm a bit obsessional about such things) if pi occurred only a few times in a simple context. Otherwise, as is the usual case, I would give up and type the same (italic) $\pi$ as everyone else. I don't even know whether \text{π} would work between dollar signs. I should do some experiments. Incidentally, the remark about yielding a blank in my previous comment was true at the time but seems to be no longer valid.

@JohnBentin Thanks! I would personally not, because I'm lazy and not too rigid about this (even though I always use straight d for differentials in my papers). Apparently, the upgreek package exists, see this \ Presumably someone saw your message and fixed the issue. Seems like extended discussions are sometimes useful!

i, j, k are also used for the component representation of vectors in 2-D and 3-D Euclidean space.   Related to quaternions but not the same thing.

@Spencer : More usually, boldface $\bf{i,j,k}$ .

@JohnBentin: I would be very surprised if TeX supported π. Maybe MathJax allows it, but I don't think you can do that in a "real" publication. You would probably have to use XeTeX (and then argue with the publisher who is using some hilariously outdated TeX stack that doesn't speak Unicode).

The claim “the natural base should be set in roman type” is simply wrong: setting it in italics is by far the more standard convention, both in current and pre-LaTeX typesetting, and borne out by for instance the AMS style guide.  A few authors choose roman, and there are reasonable arguments for that — but this answer makes it sound like the standard normative convention to follow, and that’s just not true.

I searched the internet for "Weibull" functions for dose-response and found Christian Ritz's GitHub reference for Weibull model functions, which demonstrates a technique that seems reasonable: Since $e$ is the standard name of a parameter, it can't be used for the base of the natural exponential function. As such, $\exp$ is used instead of $e^\cdot$ to represent the exponential function, as in:

The four-parameter Weibull type 1 model ('weibull1') is $$f(x)=c+(d-c)\exp(-\exp(b(\log(x)-\log(e))))\text{.}$$


That works if you don't have to reference the value of $e$ (the constant) directly.

@TonyK call it $\exp1$, as long as it's not too often.

@J.G.: Yes, I thought of that. And then I thought $yeugh$! But tastes vary, I suppose.

@TonyK $\exp \exp 0$ or $1/\exp(-1)$ might be more to your liking? j/k

Shouldn't that be $\ln$ instead of $\log$?

@Dominique I'm quoting the page I link exactly. Also, see questions like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/293783/26369 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108547/26369

yuck, I saw "log(e)" and went "isn't that just one"

@Dominique, it's implicit in the context, the same as exp(x) being e^x, not e.g. 10^x.
