# Log or Ln, Cramer Rao Lower Bound, Does it matter?

Tags: probability, statistics

As part of some self study I need to calculate the Cramer Rao Lower Bound. In some textbook and articles I see Log used and in others I see Ln used. Does it matter which I use as long as I am consistent in usage?

Comment: In this setting, $\log$ is likely the same as $\ln$. You should take a look at [this nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90613) from Michael Hardy to a similar question.

Comment: just read the nice answer, and it makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard convention for writing $\log_e x$ is $\ln x$. Some authors use $\log$ in stead of $\ln$. But in that case, the meaning is well conveyed either in the proof or in the beginning of the text where the author defines notations. In general $\ln x=2.303\log x$.