# When can I assume $\operatorname{Log}$ means the natural log?

Tags: logarithms, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have a problem that says:

Express $e^{\operatorname{Log}(3+4i)}$ in the form $x+iy$.

However, in class we usually only deal with natural log (this problem is from a textbook). How do I know when I can interpret ''Log'' as the natural log?

Comment: Once you're past calculus it's pretty much only used to mean natural log

Comment: Capital L $\operatorname{Log}$ usually has a very specific meaning when working with complex numbers, if I recall.

Comment: @pjs36 the capital just means to take the principle value of the argument.

Comment: Yes but it's an extension of the natural log to the complex numbers (or to the Riemann surface associated with `log z`).

Comment: Usually your textbook will standardize notation when it introduces logarithms, especially the capital logarithm that's used in complex analysis. Do not assume log is natural log when you look at other sources. In computer science it is often base 2, for example.

Comment: Interesting that you bring this up. The notation log(z) is used to denote the complex logarithm, as it is being stated here, but if you notice, appears in much older texts when the notation ln(z) was yet to be introduced for "pedagogical reasons". The first to introduce the notation was Irving Stringham in 1893 at UC Berkeley. For more on this historical footnote, go here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/how-did-the-notation-ln-for-log-base-e-become-so-pervasive

Answer (score 1):

Since $z\mapsto e^z$ is periodic with period $2\pi i$, it is not one-to-one, and so its inverse is a "multiple-valued function" (and so not really a "function" as textbooks define that term over the past hundred years or so).  Thus
$$
\operatorname{Log}(3+4i) = \log\sqrt{3^2+4^2} + i (\theta_0 + 2\pi n)
$$
and $\theta_0 + 2\pi n$ is any of the angels in the first quadrant whose tangent is $4/3$.

Exponentiating this is exponentiating any of the complex number that when exponentiated yield $3+4i$.  Hence
$$
e^{\operatorname{Log}(3+4i)} = 3+4i.
$$