# What is the base of $\log x$?

Tags: notation, logarithms

I've seen "$\log x$" being used in some papers (and by Wolfram|Alpha), and I was confused because so far I have only ever seen the $\log$ used with a base ( so e.g. $\log_y x$).

Am I correct that $\log x = \log_e x = \ln x$?

- If so, why is $\log x$ used over $\ln x$? Isn't the letter more expressive
  and less confusing?
- If not, what is the base of $\log x$?

Comment: This depends heavily on context, but the most common definition is $\log x = \ln x$. That said, in introductory textbooks for students, $\log$ is often used to mean $\log_{10}$, and in coding theory $\log$ often refers to $\log_2$. In general though, unless specified it typically refers to $\log_e$.

Comment: @B.Mehta thanks for the clarification. So indeed kind of confusing because it is context-dependent. Why not simply use $\lg x$ and $\ln x$ then?

Comment: Nowadays, usually $\log x=\ln x$. In older books, it can be $\log_{10} x$, especially in books dealing with numerical computations, as decimal logs were used, with the help of [tables of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_table) or [slide rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule), to do most numerical computations by hand.

Comment: For WolframAlpha you're right: $\log$ means $\ln$. In other context it depends. For example on physics the natural logarithm is usually denoted by $\ln$, and I think sometimes $\log$ denotes the logarithm on base $10$. For example here in Spain in the school $\log$ denotes presicely the logarithm in base $10$. However, I like to use this notation for the natural logarithm and I write $\log_x$ when the base is different from $e$. As a rule: if you see in the same reference $\log$ and $\log$ the first is referring to the decimal logarithm. Otherwise... who knows.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow It's hard to say for certain, but most likely just historical reasons: authors picked convention to what was most convenient, and that 'stuck' within each field of mathematics.

Comment: @B.Mehta Why not add that as an answer?

Comment: I'm going to say that when it comes to high school math *and science* textbooks that $\log $ is assumed to be base $10$ where it's usually used for scientific notation calculations where measurements are arbitrarily base on 10s.  But it depends on context.  It means either natural log or $\log_e $, or $\log_{10} $. Possibly but very rarely it could mean base 2. (That's usually noted as lg, though.  The book should clarify though.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I expected it to be too short to be an answer when I started; in hindsight I probably should have made it an answer.

Comment: @fleablood so $\lg x = \log_2 x$? I've only ever seen $\lg x$ being used to denote the decadic logarithm, i.e. $\lg x = \log_{10} x$.

Comment: Well, to be honest I've never seen log base 2 anywhere but these boards where I've seen it as lg, but I'm never seen lg or base 2 have its own notation anywhere.  And I've NEVER seen base 10 referenced  as lg.  But apparently your mileage varied.  But I stand that I've never seen lg referee to anything but base 2 and then I've only seen that on these boards.  But that's me.  ... at any rate, I think we both agree that if you see log without a base, the author is assuming a base and it's either 10 or e.  Probably e if it's an advanced math book but maybe 10 if it's an old high school book.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've now added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a standard scientific calculator, the **log** button denotes the "common logarithm", i.e. $\log_{10}$.  This is consistent with the common usage in engineering and the natural sciences; for example, the pH scale used for measuring acidity, the Richter scale used for measuring earthquake intensity, and the decibel scale used for measuring sound intensity are all defined using a base-10 logarithm.  Scientific calculators use the **ln** button to indicate the "natural logarithm", i.e. $\log_e$.

In contrast, mathematicians tend to use the symbol $\log$ to refer to $\log_e$.  That's because (from the point of view of pure mathematics) there is nothing special about the number $10$, and no real reason to define a logarithm to a a single, arbitrary privileged base.  From a pure mathematics standpoint, the only logarithm that really matters is $\log_e$, so this is what the generic symbol $\log$ refers to.

For some reason many mathematicians tend to be oblivious to the fact that outside of our own tribe nearly everyone uses the symbols **log** and **ln** to refer to different things, and  rather obstinate in insisting that $\log = \log_e$, as if notation were not merely a convention but rather somehow a law of nature or a logical necessity.  Notation is always conventional, and all conventions are local.

Comment: For this reason the “common logarithm” is often called the “decimal logarithm” $\ddot\smile$

Comment: In addition, it might be nice to note $\log_e x$ has the nice property that its derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$, which is why it's typically chosen in pure mathematics over any others.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out base 10 *is* still currently more common in the physical sciences for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This depends heavily on context, but the most common definition is $\log x=\ln x$. That said, in introductory textbooks for students, $\log$ is often used to mean $\log10$, and in coding theory $\log$ often refers to $\log2$. In general though, unless specified it typically refers to $\log_e$.

As to why there's no standardised convention it's hard to say for certain, but most likely just historical reasons: authors picked convention to what was most convenient, and that 'stuck' within each field of mathematics. More details about this could be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/how-did-the-notation-ln-for-log-base-e-become-so-pervasive?rq=1).

Comment: "The most common definition" requires context.  If you look across the natural sciences and engineering, I think the most common definition is unequivocally that $\log$ denotes $\log{10}$.  Why else would calculators maintain the distinction between $\log$ and $\ln$?

Comment: Even in mathematics, the standard convention (at least in the United States) at the level of introductory Calculus is that $\ln = \log_e$ and $\log = \log_{10}$.

Comment: @mweiss This is a fair response, my intention was to mean that in mathematics (since this is MSE after all) past the introductory level, the most common definition is $\ln$. In particular, since OP was asking specifically about mathematical papers and W|A, I felt this context was implied.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in math context without any other specification the symbols $\log$ and $\ln$ are both used to denote the natural logarithm.

Refer also to [Particular bases for logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases)